# How to output the line im checking inside of a file onto the console

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that makes a file called hardware id txt when non is present, but if it is it will look inside of it and find the hardware id, if it matches then it will print something, right now i am trying to output whats in the file first to test, no errors but the hardware id does not appear in console, i checked the file and can confirm the hardware id is inside of it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo; // unless we have a very good reason, this should
                                   // not be global
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL)
    { // update info was a success. NOW we have a GUID and can do stuff with
      // hwProfileInfo
        printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n",     hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
        printf("Hardware Profile: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileName);
        std::ofstream hwidfile { "hardwareid2.txt" };
        if (!(hwidfile << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid))
        { // will fail if can't write for any reason, like file didn't open
            std::cout << "File write failed\n";
            return -1;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "GetCurrentHwProfile failed\n";
        return -1;
    }

    getchar();
}

int check()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL) {


    string line;
    ifstream checkhwid("hardwareid2.txt");


    while(getline(checkhwid, line)) {
        cout << line;
    }

    checkhwid.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to call that 'check' function

Comment: where do i call it? sorry if im being dumb im just a bit confused.

Comment: how about calling it as the first line of main

Comment: like this: check();

Comment: it says check was not declared in this scope @pm100

Comment: you have to put a declaration before you call it, or move the definition of check to before main.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)